# rio_cogeo.cog_translate changes values in raster

Tags: python, rasterio, cloud-optimized-geotiff, rio

I've notice that in some cases the output of `rio_cogeo.cog_translate` has different pixel values than the input image, as if some sort of stretch/scaling has been applied. It seems to also happen when using the cli `rio cogeo create`.

I've tried searching stack exchange and the github issues but can't find reports of anyone having the same issue. Any ideas what may be causing this or other users seeing the same? Is there some sort of resampling that goes on that during the `cog` creation process (i.e is this expected behavior)?

EDIT 2022/01/31:
Some additional information: I discovered that this is occurring when the `ColorInterp` metadata was incorrectly defined. In my case, band 2 (which was actually the 'Green' data band) was assigned `ColorInterp=Alpha`. Using `gdal_edit.py` to correctly set this metadata stops the unexpected behavior. I believe this is directly related to the issue described [here](https://github.com/cogeotiff/rio-cogeo/issues/112). Will self-answer my question when I fully understand what is going on.

Comment: Do you use some lossy compression like JPEG? Are you comparing the values at native resolution? Overviews are naturally resampled.

Comment: Thank you for you response @user30184, and apologies for my delayed reply. I've edited the question with some additional information ... I am on the cusp of understanding the root cause of the problem, an will post an answer when it is fully clear (in hopes of helping others who find the same)